# Best way of using Indexes on huge table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I got a table with about 400-450 million records. Each day there are about 4 million inserts. That table contains 6 foreign keys (fact table data warehouse).

Now I was thinking about using Bitmap Join Indexes. But as from what I read the inserts are going to be pretty slow.

The table will get queried pretty often. Do you have a good Idea what the index strategy could look like?

Answer (score 3):

If you do not index a particular column, then you have no alternative to a full table (or partition) scan every time a predicate is placed on it. That is probably much more load over time than the overhead of maintaining indexes.

Inserts in the presence of bitmap join indexes are going to need to lookup against a dimension table, but that is only potentially inefficient for large dimension tables. You could consider using bitmap join indexes only for columns joining to smaller tables as a first step.

An alternative to indexing is to partition the table, which is also helpful for improving the efficiency of joins against very large dimension tables http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/part_warehouse.htm#CHDHEBBA

My default approach would be:

- Partition for query performance improvements, via partition pruning.
- Subpartition for join efficiency against large dimension tables
- Apply bitmap indexes to improve query performance where partition pruning will not help.

Comment: the fact table is indeed already partitioned (daily basis). seems like ill have to try step by step

Comment: What type of queries are your users running.  Are they by partition or across many partitions?  What's more important, taking a hit on the inserts with bitmap join indexes or faster query response?

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting to the point where foreign keys are too expensive and it might be time to drop them...aka ebay. Then you'll need some job running which can check for violations.